# How to make everything gray to the right of slider-thumb?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to make such a slider.

[image: slider]

I wrote this code, but I can't guess how to make the zone after the slider-thumb gray.

I found a way to do it through box-shadow, but it works if you assign input overflow:hidden, which is not suitable in my context, because my thumb gets out of input

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 255px;
  height: 16px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2.4px 2.4px 6.2px rgba(7, 7, 163, 0.72), 0px 0px 2.4px rgba(8, 8, 187, 0.72);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #D012FF 0%, #0B9191 100%);
  border-radius: 21.6px;
  color: #13bba4;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 2.4px 2.4px 9.5px rgba(4, 16, 14, 0.78), 0px 0px 2.4px rgba(9, 36, 32, 0.78);
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #A00BC5 0%, #1B5454 100%);
  ;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7.8px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 16.22px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Firefox**: you can use `::-moz-range-progress` and `::-moz-range-track`
- **IE**: you can use `::-ms-fill-lower` and `::-ms-fill-upper`
- **Chrome**: this one is tricky. You can change the color of the slider and thumb simultaneously by adjusting the `accent-color` on the input itself (using gradients is not possible..). If you want them to be a different color. You can add `overflow: hidden;` to the input itself, and a `box-shadow` (e.g. `box-shadow: -255px 0 0 255px blue;`) to your `::-webkit-slider-thumb`. The downside of that is that it also stops your thumb from overflowing and `box-shadow` doesn't allow a gradient.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use it in Edge? I write like this but it doesn't work

&::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #D012FF 0%, #0B9191 100%);
  }

  &::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: gray;
  }

Comment: `::-ms-fill-lower` and `::-ms-fill-upper` is only for IE (Internet Explorer)